# Firebase / Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got some issues regarding the integration of Firebase in my Android Unity app.

I created a project on firebase with my Unity Bundle Identifier. 
In authentification I enabled email and anonymous (I just exactly follow all the steps provided by Firebase in their tuto).
On Unity side I got the last firebase plugin.
First of all I started to have some manifest issues:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. Error:
>   [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml,
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\WheelRotation\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:10]
>   Trying to merge incompatible
>   /manifest/application/service[@name=com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService]
>   element

To solve this issues I just updated my manifest on Unity side to be able to compile the app and launch it on my android phone.
I succeeded to do that but when looking at the Firebase/Authentification/ Users, my Android app didn't appear.

Furthermore, when Using firebase cloud messaging interface, I can't succeed to send message (I can select the app, then click on Send but when I check my message no message was sent (the Sent column stays on 0) and obviously I don't receive the message on my android phone.

Thx in advance for your precious help.
Regards.

I'm using Unity Version: 5.4.1p2 (really need this version for specific plugins) all all other plugin are uptodate (JDK and Android sdk)

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered a bug in the newer Firebase version with Unity which relates to the ComponentDiscovery Service. Since I don't know how to mark as possible duplicate, I repost my solution here, which may help you:

> The solution behind this seems to be the package name variable, which
>   unity won't replace by the actual package name in the latest builds.
>
> https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-gradle-cannot-read-packagename-from-gradleout-src-main-androidmanifest-xml.524587/
>   proposes a temporary fix, by renaming the `package="${applicationId}"`
>   variable inside the "\Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml" on
>   line 4 with the actual package name e.g :
>   `package="com.MyCompany.MyGame"`